# Error occurred while opening logfile C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, window

I need to restart the MS SQL server service every morning because my web client site can not connect.
However, when I start my services it works. I don't know what is causing the problem.
I found this in my error log.

```
sqlservr (4052) An attempt to open the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.log"  
for read only access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): 
"Access is denied. ".  
The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).

sqlservr (3000) An attempt to open the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Api.chk"  
for read / write access failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".  
The open file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8).
```

Hope somebody can help me fix this.

Answer (score 22):

Your serviceaccount need access to the folder:

```
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Sum
```

Go to the folder and add the account with read/write permissions.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2811566

Comment: If you're using the default SQL installation options your service account will be running as "Network Service", so granting that Full Control to this folder fixed it for me thanks. I wonder why MS forget these new identities (Local/Network Service) from their default permissions, they have been around long enough. This is still occurring on Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2017!

Comment: I met the same problem, used the same solution but still don't work...OS winserver 2019, sql server 2017